# How do you add a blog function to Plone 3?

Tags: plone, blogs, plone-3.x

We currently use Plone 3 for our training website and want to add a blog.  Is this something that we can change or do we have to pay to add this function?

Comment: Stock plone can do blogging pretty well also. Just create a collection with reverse order sorting on creation date of your news items, set the collection to the default view item for the root of the site, turn off syndication and you're good to go.

Answer (score 5):

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.blog.star was the best solution last time I had this need. Should work with Plone 3 and 4.